# Resending Data to REST

Tags: python, rest, splunk, data-retrieval

I am **very** new to this and don't have much knowledge of the correct terms..  but I have rest api that sends data to Splunk.  I want to find a way to resend only data that has changed.  For example... I send 30 minutes worth of data to Splunk.  After the data has been sent to Splunk, one minute of the data has been changed (the user has edited the data or updated it of some sort).  I don't want to resend all 30 minutes of the data just to update the one minute that has changed.  Is there a way to only resend the new data? Maybe using a script or something?

I would really appreciate some insight on this and maybe some example codes if the solution requires writing some code to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! I think the Splunk function `Entity.update()` can do what you're describing. Are you new to python too? How is the data that you're sending to Splunk stored?

Comment: Yes, also new to python.. I believe the data comes from the DB to the rest api.. I will read about Entity.update() and see if that is what we're looking to achieve. Thanks!